# ggplot Stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I would like to create a stacked chart using ggplot2 and geom_bar.

```
This is my data:
Date          D1    D2    D3
2017-05-08    .3    .5    .2
2017-02-22    .4    .4    .2
2016-11-23    .1    .5    .4
2016-05-13    .2    .6    .2
```

I want a stacked chart where the x-axis is the Year, the y-axis is the proportion of D1, D2, D3 (with D1, D2, D3 in different color).

This is what I am thinking

## Plot Chart

```
ggplot(data = data1, mapping = aes(x = as.numeric(format(data1$Date, '%Y')), fill=D1)) 
+ geom_bar()
```

However, this will only plot D1. I am not sure what I need to do to add in the D2 and D3 on the same plot.

Manually changing the data, I can create something like this. But I would like to do this in a more efficient way.
[image]

Comment: I guess I can, but prefer not to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
require(ggplot2)

df$Date <- substr(df$Date,1,4)

plotDf <- melt(df, id.vars='Date')

plotDf <- aggregate(value ~ variable + Date, 
                    mean, na.rm=TRUE, data=plotDf)
```

Output:

[image]

Sample data:

```
require(data.table)

df <- fread("Date          D1    D2    D3
             2017-05-08    .3    .5    .2
             2017-02-22    .4    .4    .2
             2016-11-23    .1    .5    .4
             2016-05-13    .2    .6    .2")
```

Comment: This is solves part of my problem, I am also looking to aggregate the dates into just years and averaging the D1 D2 D3